# Rails direct upload to Amazon S3 using Activeadmin + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, activeadmin

I am using Activeadmin and Paperclip to make images upload on my Rails app. When I try to upload big files to S3 the timeout error occurs, so I have to implement the direct upload to S3.

Does anyone know how can I make it? I could't figure it out...

Comment: http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [really nice article](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) I've used when was first time setting up the `AA+s3+Paperclip`.

It has decent explanations + [example app on Github](https://github.com/uberllama/s3_direct_upload_example), so you can check it live.

In AA the form would look something like this:

```
form multipart: true do |f|
  # f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
  f.inputs do
    f.input :image_name #or whatever field is called
  end
    f.has_many :attachments do |a|
      if a.object.persisted?
        link_to image_tag(a.object.encoded_url, class: 'image-preview'), a.object.encoded_url, target: "_blank"
      else
        a.inputs do
          a.s3_file_field(:attachment, as: :file, class: 'js-s3_file_field')
        end +
        a.inputs do
          a.input(:s3_url, as: :hidden, input_html: { class: "s3_url" })
        end
      end  
    end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm having problems with the regex that validates the direct url, which is:
`DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/s3\.amazonaws\.com\/myapp#{!Rails.env.production? ? "\\-#{Rails.env}" : ''}\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze`

Did you have any problem with that?

Comment: getting undefined method `s3_file_field' for #<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0x007f2dd178b3c8> @AndreyDeineko any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be in the comments.  Thanks Andrey for the tutorial link.

http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and